# Selenium Web Scraping Opens Separate Browser

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, beautifulsoup, browser

I am working on a project analyzing the [Supercluster Astronaut Database](https://www.supercluster.com/astronauts).  I posted a StackOverflow question a few weeks ago about scraping the data from the website and got the code below from one of the helpful posters.

My only remaining issue with this process is that when I load the code, a browser window pops open linked to the data source I am trying to scrape.  I've tried tinkering with this code to get the browser window to not pop up by commenting out a few lines here and there, but nothing I've tried seems to work properly.  Can someone help point me in the right direction to modify the code below to not have a browser pop up?

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
import time


data = []

url = 'https://www.supercluster.com/astronauts?ascending=false&limit=300&list=true&sort=launch%20order'

driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
driver.maximize_window()
time.sleep(5)
driver.get(url)
time.sleep(5)

soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'lxml')
driver.close()
tags = soup.select('.astronaut_cell.x')

for item in tags:
    name = item.select_one('.bau.astronaut_cell__title.bold.mr05').get_text()
    #print(name.text)
    country = item.select_one('.mouseover__contents.rel.py05.px075.bau.caps.small.ac')
    if country:
        country=country.get_text()
    #print(country)
    
    data.append([name, country])



cols=['name','country']
df = pd.DataFrame(data,columns=cols)

print(df)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're looking to run your code in `headless` mode. You can add a headless argument in the `Options()` class to achieve this.

Code :-

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
import time


data = []

url = 'https://www.supercluster.com/astronauts?ascending=false&limit=300&list=true&sort=launch%20order'

options = Options()
options.add_argument("--headless")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install(),options=options)
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get(url)
time.sleep(10)

soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'lxml')
driver.close()
tags = soup.select('.astronaut_cell.x')

for item in tags:
    name = item.select_one('.bau.astronaut_cell__title.bold.mr05').get_text()
    #print(name.text)
    country = item.select_one('.mouseover__contents.rel.py05.px075.bau.caps.small.ac')
    if country:
        country=country.get_text()
    #print(country)
    
    data.append([name, country])



cols=['name','country']
df = pd.DataFrame(data,columns=cols)

print(df)
```